# Find $\iint_{\Sigma} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{\sigma}$ with $\vec{F}(x,y,z)=(0,0,z)$ and $\Sigma$ the ellipsoid $(\frac xa)^2+(\frac yb)^2+(\frac zc)^2=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My attempt:

I tried giving $\Sigma$ a parameterization in cylindrical coordinates: $-c \le z \le c$ and $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$. For $r$ I got this ugly expression $$ \frac{ab}{c} \sqrt{\frac{c^2-z^2}{b^2\cos^2\theta+a^2\sin^2\theta}}.$$ And therefore $$ \vec{\varphi}(\theta,z)=(\frac{ab}{c} \cos\theta\sqrt{\frac{c^2-z^2}{b^2\cos^2\theta+a^2\sin^2\theta}},\frac{ab}{c} \sin\theta\sqrt{\frac{c^2-z^2}{b^2\cos^2\theta+a^2\sin^2\theta}},z). \quad (1)$$

I believe there's an easier method to calculate this surface integral considering the elementary form of $\vec{F}$.

I know that the given surface integral can be rewritten as ($\vec{n}$ oriented outward)$$ \iint_{\Sigma}\vec{F}\cdot \vec{n}d\sigma.$$ The first two component of the vector function $\vec{F}$ are $0$, which means that the integral can be found considering only the $z$-components of both $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{n}$. To find the $z$-component of $\vec{n}$, I'd have to integrate the first two components in $(1)$ with respect to $\theta$ and to $z$. Maybe it will work out, but I'm scared to begin.

Is there an easier way to parameterize the given surface, or even to approach this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried applying the divergence theorem? That may help, but no promises as I haven't tried to work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out some more details in light of my original comment and the divergence theorem will prove useful. Hopefully this should get you going.

Hint: Let $E$ denote the region bounded by the ellipsoid $\Sigma$. Then, by the divergence theorem, we have
$$\int_\Sigma F \cdot n \ d\sigma = \int_E \mathrm{div} F \ dV = \int_E 1 \ dV = \mathrm{vol}(E).$$